# How to remove empty space on UITableView header after removing the header?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to set the header view of the `UITableView` (not header of a section) to nil after setting it to a view.

I tried lots of combination to do this including the following, my view is removed but I still get an empty space which I never get If I never set the header view.

```
    [_tableViewController.tableView.tableHeaderView removeFromSuperview];
    _tableViewController.tableView.tableHeaderView=nil;
    [_tableViewController.tableView reloadData];
```

(I have also tried to set a view with zero height and set the frame accordingly but that doesn't work too. (setting it to 1px height works, but it is not a good solution and it also still has some space there...)

What am I doing wrong in here?

**update:** I found that this is caused by `UITableViewStyleGrouped`, after changing table style to `UITableViewStylePlain` it works. But I have to keep using `UITableViewStyleGrouped`.
Isn't it possible? If so, why? If yes, how?

Comment: I deleted my answer. I believe I know the reason now. You are trying this code from **viewcontrollerA** to the remove tableView.tableHeaderView from **viewcontrollerB** right? You can not simply do this. There are 2 ways, you either implement the delegate or use NSNotification to do that.

Comment: I am going out for dinner now.. please add more info or upload a project to Github. If no one helps you fix the problem, I will help you later when I am back.

Comment: Ricky, I have updated my question. I found that this is related to table style, but I still couldn't figure out a solution as I have to use UITableViewStyleGrouped. (By the way, for your question: I have only viewcontrollerA and tableviewController)

Comment: So, you are calling the above code from viewControllerA right?

Comment: Yes, and tableViewController is also member of the same object. You have said that it is working for you. Would you please try setting the style of the table to UITableViewStyleGrouped and try to set the header to nil?

Comment: When I mentioned "it was working for me", it is because tableview inside the same ViewController that I am calling the code. If you want do the above, you can not do like this, you will have to use delegate or use NSNotification. I will help you for a bit on how to do that.

Comment: I have edited the answer below, I am using the NSNotification method as it is easier for me. Please check and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:-

Inside **tableViewController**

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(removeheaderView) name:@"removeheaderView" object:nil];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
  [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"removeheaderView" object:nil];
}

-(void)removeheaderView{
  [self.tableView.tableHeaderView removeFromSuperview];
  self.tableView.tableHeaderView=nil;
  [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

In **viewControllerA**, replace

```
 [_tableViewController.tableView.tableHeaderView removeFromSuperview];
 _tableViewController.tableView.tableHeaderView=nil;
 [_tableViewController.tableView reloadData];
```

with

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"removeheaderView" object:nil];
```

Please try and let me know the result.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work too. Also, I tested this like this too: I "never" set the tableHeaderView and used your code block. (So, setting tableHeaderView to nil, while it was already not set) I got the same result! There must be something else that breaks it..

Comment: Yes, I actually tried your solution, it works on my side too. I think it is something else on your side that make you see the space. Are you able to upload a sample project to github? Or May be add more code related to the tableview?

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late yet posting my answer so that others can benefit out of this.

Try:

```
tableView.tableHeaderView?.removeFromSuperview()
tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude))
tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Set an UIView with height as CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude instead of '0'.

This worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

You should implement the datasource method of UITableView:

`-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`

and set it to 0.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I mean the header of the table not the sections.